# Convert string to directory path

Tags: export, blend-files, path

```
class Export():
    def execute(self, context):
        conf_path=context.scene.conf_path
        dir=conf_path
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx({
            "object":None,
            "active_object":None,
            "selected_objects":objects},
            filepath=dir("//{}.{}".format('abc','.fbx')),
            use_selection=True,
            )


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.conf_path = bpy.props.StringProperty \
    (
      name = "Root Path",
      default = "",
      description = "Define the root path of the project",
      subtype = 'DIR_PATH'
    )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.conf_path
```

Its not full file but Its just for demonstration. My issue is the "dir" object. As I run the code it says error that dir is an str object and cannnot be called. I want to know how I can convert this dir to an path so I can use it to save my export object. I tried using  dir=Path(conf_path), but it shows error WINDOWSPATH is not callable.

I just want to use this as my export directory but Like I said it shows it as a string

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have an extra period in your string format.  You either need to remove the period between the curly bracket pairs or the one in '.fbx'
2. `dir` in your code is a variable name.  It hides any dir function that you might have elsewhere in the code.
3. [In exporters, filepath takes a string argument](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html).

This code will do what you meant to do

```
    def execute(self, context):
        from pathlib import Path
 
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx({
            "object":None,
            "active_object":None,
            "selected_objects":objects},
            filepath=str(Path(context.scene.conf_path) / "abc.fbx"),
            use_selection=True,
            )
```

and you should move the `import pathlib` to the top of your file with the other imports.  I only put it here because you do need to import the library to use it.

EDIT: after clarification in the comments, I edited to use the conf_path.

Comment: Actually you misunderstood my question. I don't want to use the blend file directory I want to use a custom one, thats why I have define a bpy.types.scene.conf_name but problem is this returns a string object, If I tend to assign this value to dir as(dir=context.scene.conf_name) it will say filepath can't be a string. Basically my question is to convert the conf_name from str to a file path. thank you. There is an image of my conf_name in UI I attached

Answer (score 1):

In my code, there is a string property `conf_name` which is being used to accept a directory from the user [image]

Final solution is either use `filepath= bpy.data.filepath("//abc.fbx"):` for saving in blend file directory.
Second if case is you want to store it to custom filepath use code as below

```
file="name"
dir="C:\Users\naman\Desktop\"  
ext="fbx"
op=bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx
op({
   "object":None,
   "active_object":None,
   "selected_objects":objects},
    filepath=(dir+"//{}.{}".format(file,ext)),
    use_selection=True,
    )
```